# Use different date format on Google Sheets chart?

Tags: date, google-sheets, charts, format

I am sampling data twice a day and sending it via IFTTT to Google Sheets. All working well but ideally I would like the date format on the chart to be different to that in the sheet and I can't see an obvious way to do that other than to create another column in the sheet. See attached, is it possible to have the date without the time on the chart?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs), or the [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts)  of Apps Script.

The documentation on Google Visualizations has many examples, its not straight forward at first, but with a couple of examples you'll get the hang of it and tailor your chart to your desired output.

In your case, the hint is to modify the horizontal axis format.

See this example to start with: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#formatting-axis,-gridline,-and-tick-labels